# Redisplay original Model with .Include( related-entity ) after update validation fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When a user sends a GET request to edit a record I am loading the model sent ot the view with related entities using .Include() like this:

```
 var client = await _context.Client
                             .Include(c => c.Office)
                             .Where(c => c.client_id == id)
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
 return View(client);
```

When a user POST back the edit form and required fields are missing `ModelState.IsValid == false` then no update is performed and the model with unsaved changes is sent back to the view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Client client_edited )
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            return View(client_edited); // .Include(c => c.Office) is missing
    }
}
```

**How do you return the view model posted (with the users pending changes) and also re-attach the required .Include()?**

When I requery the model (client) record the pending changes are lost.

I am trying to do something like re-query the client w/ includes and then copy the client with pending changes over the top. Something like...

```
var client = await _context.Client
                             .Include(c => c.Office)
                             .Where(c => c.client_id == id)
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

 // need to copy pending client_edited changes to the client 
 // but does not work because it overwrites the .Include(c => c.Office)
 client = client_edited 

 return View(client_edited);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps others...

Based on a [blog post by Lori Peterson Entity Framework cloning,](http://lorifpeterson.com/?p=75) see ***EF Copying Current Values***, I was able to solve the issue with a few lines of code, example below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Client client_posted)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Record is missing required values");

    // requery the client entity from our db to get related child entities
    var client_current = await _context.Client
                                        .Include(c => c.Office)
                                        // include 4 or 5 more entities here
                                        .Where(c => c.client_id == client_posted.client_id)
                                        .AsNoTracking()
                                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    // now replace client_current values with client_posted values by

    // 1 - add entity to your db context (we are not saving it)
    _myDbContext.Client.Add(client_posted);

    // 2 - use the db context to extract current values from the client entity posted
    var client_posted_values =_myDbContext.Entry(client_posted).CurrentValues;

    // 3 - copy the extracted values to the client_current we re-queried from db
    _myDbContext.Entry(client_current).CurrentValues.SetValues(client_posted_values);

    // 4 return the view passing client with original values and the attached office entity(ies)
    return View(client_current);
  }
  // otherwise ModelState is valid, do the update here
  ...
  ...
}
```